# Senior cat has dental abscess

Tags: medicines, senior-pet, dental-care, surgery, pain

I have a 19-20 year old cat. Long story short, over the past week and a half it seems a dental issue arose and an abscess started to explode the past 2 days. Upon the vet's inspection today, he seemed to ruptured it accidentally "Oops I ruptured it". He did some CBC and chem analysis (not sure if anyone wants to see), and concluded his kidneys and him being anemic won't make a great candidate for surgery. Also a bit below body temperature. (Though there was no explanation for that. He was shaved recently for his knots and some flea treatment).

But I don't know, I don't feel right after this appointment. He was perfectly fine over the holidays and what not, and the fact he just ruptured it by just grabbing at his face immediately upset me a bit. I saw some vets online being careful saying they just don't want to outright rupture it. The vet then proceeded to give me antibiotic and said it won't do much because there's pus that's just going to keep forming, and said I should consider putting him down because he's going to stop eating eventually and drinking because of the pain, and vomit/diarrhea from pus being ingested. Though he didn't even give me a pain medication. So now when I got home, he's eating and drinking, but now he's being hesitant finishing his food because it's bothering him more now I guess?

Honestly I don't know what I'm asking. Maybe I'm in denial. A dental specialist place I contacted said based on what I wrote, should be in critical care at the moment, not home, though the place is pretty far. Just very upset. :(. Does anyone know a good quality place in the NYC/Tri state area maybe that can take a look? A lot of the hospitals have okayish reviews, which worry me.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I am sad that you and your cat suffer. Please try to focus onto one question or aim you want to reach. This site will close questions that ask for opinion based answers or are not focused. As you have a diagnosis from the vet, you could ask how a casual treatment of this would be done. We can not take decisions from you, but we can give you information so you can make a well informed decision. I wish you and your cat all the best!

Comment: TBH I do understand your vet. It would probably be best to pull the tooth, but you can only do that when the cat is in full anesthesia. For such an old cat with the underlying medical problems you describe, there's a high risk he won't wake up again. And it's natural for an abscess to rupture eventually. If the vet didn't do it accidentally, it would have ruptured eventually on its own. Also keep in mind that cats hide medical problems as long as possible, so you just didn't notice earlier what was wrong. Continue the antibiotics treatment for now and see if the situation improves.

Comment: @Elmy Thanks for the response. There's no way to be under local anesthesia, like humans? I imagine sure the cat may move around, but unfortunately it seems he's just getting more tame. He couldn't even properly jump this morning. :(

Comment: @Elmy Thank you for the response. My baby ended up passing away.

Comment: @TheCoolest2 I'm really sorry for your loss. There will always come a time for us to say goodbye and in this case, I'm afraid there was no way to prolong your time together. If it's any consolation for you, I think you did the right thing.